# Passing Service data from module config to Controller from $routeProvider?

Tags: angularjs

I am really new to angular and have been reading a number of tutorials etc and have the following problem:

**search-module.js**

```
var Search = angular.module('SearchApp',["ngCookies","ngRoute"]);

Search.run(function ($http, $cookies) {
    $http.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies['csrftoken'];
});

Search.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            controller:'searchCtrl',
            resolve: {
                inv_items: function (InventoryService){
                    return InventoryService.get('red');
                }
            }
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        })
});
```

**data-service.js**

```
Search.factory('InventoryService', function ($http, $q) {

    var api_url = "api/inventory/";

    return {

        get: function (inventory) {
            var url = api_url + inventory;
            var defer = $q.defer();
            $http({method: 'GET', url: url}).
                success(function (data, status, headers, config){
                    defer.resolver(data);
                })
                .error(function (data,status, headers, config){
                    defer.reject(status);
                });
            return defer.promise;
        }
    }
});
```

**search-controller.js**

```
Search.controller('searchCtrl', function($scope){

    $scope.selected = 'have';

    $scope.setSection = function(section){
        $scope.selected = section;
    };

    $scope.isSelected = function(section){
        return $scope.selected == section;
    };

});
```

Like I mentioned previously I am really new to angular just picked it up yesterday. Basically from what I have written I understand that when the URL is '/' then the service will be initiated and the controller will be called? What I want to know is why cant I use inv_items in my controller? I get the following [error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=inv_itemsProvider%20%3C-%20inv_items).

Do I need to pass some sort of global to the controller which will contain inv_items or am I missing some important piece of knowledge?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The resolve variable 'inv_items' isn't automatically added to your scope of 'searchCtrl'.

```
Search.controller('searchCtrl', function($scope, inv_items){ //Add this
    $scope.inv_items = inv_items; //And this
    $scope.selected = 'have';

    $scope.setSection = function(section){
        $scope.selected = section;
    };

    $scope.isSelected = function(section){
        return $scope.selected == section;
    };
});
```

Granted that the rest of the code works, your 'inv_items' should now be available in that scope.

Comment: Hi, so I tried that in my code initially and got the error I linked above. Does this mean that there is an error in another part of the code? If I omit inv_items from the controller there is no error raised in console.